# Python - compare 2 lists, match and keep duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

This is not a simple matching of two lists. List 2 is longer than List 1.
**Match by the alphabet.**

The two lists are:

```
List 1     List 2
a-1        a-2
b-1        z-99        
c-1        a-3
           z-99
           b-2
```

I want to return this result:

```
List 1     List 2
a-1        a-2
           a-3
b-1        b-2
```

Any idea what is the way to do this? ]
Thank you!

Comment: I cannot see the rule of matching. Further, which items should I keep?

Comment: @thomas Match by the alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.merge`:

```
df1 = df[["List 1"]]
df2 = df[["List 2"]]
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1["List 1"].str[0], right_on=df2["List 2"].str[0])
print(df3.drop("key_0", 1))
```

Output:

```
  List 1 List 2
0    a-1    a-2
1    a-1    a-3
2    b-1    b-2
```

Comment: i think this is it ! I knew it should be something related to pandas merge but didnt know how to do it. thanks